# How to rename columns while overwriting potential duplicates in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a `pandas.dataframe`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame( {'one': pd.Series([1., 2., 3.], 
                                     index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
                    'two': pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.], 
                                     index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']),
                    'three': pd.Series([0., 6., 1.], 
                                     index=['b', 'c', 'd']),
                    'two_': pd.Series([1., 2., 5, 4.], 
                                     index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])})
```

or

```
print (df) 
#   one  three  two  two_
#a    1    NaN    1     1
#b    2      0    2     2
#c    3      6    3     5
#d  NaN      1    4     4
```

and I have a map which renames certain columns as such

```
name_map = {'one': 'one', 'two': 'two_'} 
df.rename(columns=name_map)
#    one  three  two_  two_
# a    1    NaN     1     1
# b    2      0     2     2
# c    3      6     3     5
# d  NaN      1     4     4
```

(occasionally `name_map` might map a column to itself, e.g. 'one' -> 'one'). What I want in the end is the object

```
#    one_  three  two_ 
#a     1    NaN      1    
#b     2      0      2    
#c     3      6      3    
#d   NaN      1      4
```

How I should remove potential duplicates before renaming?

Comment: I think, you meant `name_map = {'one': 'one_', 'two': 'two_'}`? and not `name_map = {'one': 'one', 'two': 'two_'}`

Comment: The values in `two_` columns are different. Which one do you want to keep ?

Comment: @JohnGalt, I actually want to map 'one' to 'one', as the map is generated by another function , and this is a possible result of that function. I suppose I can drop items that are mapped to themselves... and then run your code below

Comment: @fixxxer I want to keep the one that was originally 'two'

Comment: @fixxxer I should clarify, there might be other columns as well, which I would not want to remove. I edited the question.

Comment: the problems stems from the fact that pandas does not complain when I am creating a duplicated column.. seems like this type of functionality should be added..

Comment: Well, the problem here is identifying the columns uniquely and finding the "potential duplicates". If you can do that (and you don't have two columns with the same name),  you can do drop and rename easily.

Comment: if you edit your answer to do this I will select it

Answer (score 3):

First get the common columns `list(set(name_map.values()) & set(df.columns))` and `drop()` them. And, then `rename()` it using `columns=name_map`

```
In [16]: (df.drop(list(set(name_map.values()) & set(df.columns)), axis=1)
            .rename(columns=name_map))
Out[16]:
   one_  two_
a     1     1
b     2     2
c     3     3
d   NaN     4
```

Answer (score 0):

I have one method, but it seems a bit messy (dealing with the NaN values contributes to the messiness)

```
potential_duplicates = [ new 
                         for old,new in name_map.items() 
                         if new in list(df) # if the new column name exists
                         and 
                         pd.np.any( df[old][df[old]==df[old]]  # if said column differs from the one to be renames 
                                     != df[new][df[new]==df[new]] ) ]

df.drop( potential_duplicates, axis = 1, inplace=True)

df.rename( columns=name_map) 

#    one_  two_ 
#a     1     1
#b     2     2
#c     3     3
#d   NaN     4
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to drop the columns which are not present in the `name_map` values list (since you want to remove the first `two` column)

```
In [74]: df
Out[74]: 
   one  two  two_
a    1    1     1
b    2    2     2
c    3    3     5
d  NaN    4     4

In [76]: df.drop([col for col in df.columns if col not in name_map.keys()], axis=1)
Out[76]: 
   one  two
a    1    1
b    2    2
c    3    3
d  NaN    4
```